# Transform failed with error code 525: plotly.js error while saving plotly image while running in docker

Tags: docker, plotly

I have a docker container running R and python.

It pulls data and generates plotly plots for n companies

```
plot1 = function(company){
get data
fig = plotly
fig
}
```

I loop through a list of ~ 50 companies, call this `plot1` function, and the save it using `kaleido`, and `save_image(plot1(company), file = f )`

It works for the first 20 companies, and then on the 21st, I receive the error: `Transform failed with error code 525: plotly.js error`

I ran the container 3x, and each time it failed at the same location/file.

The `plot1()` result  is a standard plotly figure when run from my local source

I only get the error when running in the container, as when I run the source code, it saves without issue.

Are there any suggestions how to overcome this?